# When I close my Dev environment I lose all my deployments? How do I preserve my deployments

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When first time I deployed any business network I can connect the network and `composer-playground`. But when I restart my PC after shutdown, I can't connect the network but the `composer-playground` showing the card related the network and can connect by the card. Should I need to deploy business network every time after opening my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a `bash script` named `fabricDev` so that I can easily start and stop `docker-compose` of Fabric. I added as an answer so that others can use this script.

**fabricDev.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

start_fabric() {
    cd ./fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer
    docker-compose start
    echo
    echo 'Fabric DEV environment started'
}

stop_fabric() {
    cd ./fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer
    docker-compose stop
    echo
    echo 'Fabric DEV environment stopped'
}

case $1 in 
    start)
        start_fabric
        ;;
    stop)
        stop_fabric
        ;;
    *)
esac
```

Need to run `./fabricDev.sh stop` and `./fabricDev.sh start`

Answer (score 2):

When you restart the environment with `./startFabric.sh` all of the dev environment gets re-initialized. If you want not to lose the earlier deployed BNA then don't use `./startFabric` & `./stopFabric` scripts. You have to run `docker-compose stop` to stop fabric containers in `./fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer`. When restart your dev environment then run `docker ps -q -a | xargs docker start`. This will start all dangling containers.

Comment: indeed or just `docker-compose start` from the same directory as pointed out above to make use of the docker-compose.yml file